# How to group dates by week and weekday with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have data from which I should count rows by weeks and weekdays. As result I should get

Starting day of the week, weekday, count of data for that day

I have tried this code:

```
var GroupedByDate = from r in dsDta.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                        let eventTime = (DateTime)r["EntryTime"]
                        group r by new
                        {
                            WeekStart = DateTime(eventTime.Year, eventTime.Month, eventTime.AddDays(-(int)eventTime.DayOfWeek).Day),
                            WeekDay = eventTime.DayOfWeek
                        } 
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            g.Key,
                            g.WeekStart,
                            g.WeekDay,
                            LoadCount = g.Count()
                        };
```

However, from DateTime(eventTime.Year, ...) 
I get an error "C# non-invocable member datetime cannot be used like a method."

What to do differently?

Comment: You are missing `new` when trying to create a new DateTime instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate error is due to you missing the `new` part from your constructor call. However, even with that, you'd still have a problem as you're using the month and year of the existing date, even if the start of the week is in a previous month or year.

Fortunately, you can simplify it very easily:

```
group r by new
{
    WeekStart = eventTime.AddDays(-(int)eventTime.DayOfWeek)),
    WeekDay = eventTime.DayOfWeek
}
```

Or if `eventTime` isn't always a date, use `eventTime.Date.AddDays(...)`.

Alternatively, for clarity, you could extract a separate method:

```
group r by new
{
    WeekStart = GetStartOfWeek(eventTime)
    WeekDay = eventTime.DayOfWeek
}

...

private static DateTime GetStartOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    // Whatever implementation you want
}
```

That way you can test the implementation of `GetStartOfWeek` separately, and also make it more complicated if you need to without it impacting your query.

Comment: What about if `eventTime` doesn't have its ***time*** set to `00:00:00`? Your `WeekStart` groups will probably look strange, right? (I think the point of using a `new DateTime` was also to get rid of the time part). Aaaand... That's why you got that *separate method* part! Nice

Comment: @Rafalon: I was assuming they were already dates - although using `.Date` would be an easy way to fix that if not. I'll edit the answer appropriately.

Comment: Having `Time` in `eventTime`, I would find it strange if it didn't include time though ^^